# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Add a device to a topic using curl command

Tags: php, curl, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

For now I can send a notification to a single device using the curl command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAxxxxxE4:xxxxxxxuXog" --header Content-Type:"application/json; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -d '{"to":"DeviceToken","notification":{"title":"Test","body":"Test Message","icon":"icon-192x192.png"}}' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

This works great. Now I try to scale the number of recipients by using the topic functionality.

I tried to add a device to the topic "svp" by using the curl command:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=AAAxxxxxE4:xxxxxxxuXog" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/DeviceToken/topics/svp
```

Here I get the error message:

```
{"error":"InvalidToken"}
```

But I'm sure, both, the Authorization key and the token are correct. (I still can send notifications with it).

Can anybody help me to find the solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed the `rel` in your cURL request, between the token and the topic name. As seen in the [Instance ID docs](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_a_relation_mapping_for_an_app_instance), the format should be:

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME
```

Comment: no, this will not change anything...

When regarding the documentation of FCM, I'm not sure at all that the IID-TOKEN is the same like the token which is returned from `messaging.getToken()`...

Comment: @PM84 It still didn't work even after adding in the `rel`? Hmm. Well, it should be the same as the messaging token. They did mention *registration token* in the docs. And AFAIK, there's no other kind of token. Have you tried encoding the token? If it still doesn't work, then it's already outside the intended behavior. I suggest contacting Firebase Support for further help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME did not work for me. It seemed to me that I was doing everything correctly but what I decided to do was to try the equivalent of that by using https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd and sending only one token:

```
$curlUrl = "https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd";
$mypush = array("to"=>"/topics/toronto", "registration_tokens"=>array("acwAw4F8b0W:AMA91bEAKsN1aGjMm5xsobxBHxbYZLfioTPMEIN90njdiK5C2MnOYF4NcOy6ot6BFanMTBIoKRGcyev2RJuydGWt1XHwsniNZ6h8Pjvn9Fqth-Mqgj_5-YN9pt_nMAtgG8blc5bodWyA"));
$myjson = json_encode($mypush);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, True);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myjson);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Authorization:key=[My authorization key]'));
//getting response from server
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I could add the token to the topic successfully. What was returned was this:

```
{"results":[{}]}
```

But then I went to confirm to the topics by using https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN that the token had been successfully added to the topic the way I wanted it and yes, everything worked correctly for me using https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/IID_TOKEN. So if you are having problems with https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/IID_TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME, you can simply use https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd the way I did it.